# Read specific area or string in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, string, passwords, area

I have a text file I have written user data to. Username, E-Mail and Password.

That's how the userfile looks like for now

> [<< LOGIN >>]
>
> Username: admin
>
> Password: 12345678
>
> E-Mail: hue@hue.hue
>
> [<< LOGIN END >>]

#### Now for the question.

How can I tell python to specifically read the password only? I mean, it may be possible for now that we know what the password is and what its lenght is. But how am I supposed to read the password later when I encrypt it and get some gibberish with 30+ characters?

Comment: What have you tried? Usually you just keep reading the lines and discarding them until you hit the specific line.

Comment: there might be lot of user and password right???

Comment: the line with `Password:` will be the line you want so why do you think that will be hard to find?

Comment: I've played around with if statements and couldn't handle to make things work. Basically I tried something like [if 'Password: ' + login.loginUserPassword in readUF:] or [if readUF == 'Password: ' + login.loginUserPassword:]. I managed to ask if the user input is actually in the text file, but there's still a problem. For example when the password is 123 and the user input is 1, it will return true, because the string 1 is indeed in 123.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line will contain password so just split once and get the second element:

```
In [20]: from simplecrypt import encrypt

In [21]: ciph = encrypt('password', "12345678")

In [22]: line = "Password: " + ciph

In [23]: line
Out[23]: 'Password: sc\x00\x01\x0cP\xa1\xee\'$"\xc1\x85\xe0\x04\xd2wg5\x98\xbf\xb4\xd0\xacr\xd3\\\xbc\x9e\x00\xf1\x9d\xbe\xdb\xaa\xe6\x863Om\xcf\x0fc\xdeX\xfa\xa5\x18&\xd7\xcbh\x9db\xc9\xbeZ\xf6\xb7\xd3$\xcd\xa5\xeb\xc8\xa9\x9a\xfa\x85Z\xc5\xb3%~\xbc\xdf'

In [24]: line.split(None,1)[1]
Out[24]: 'sc\x00\x01\x0cP\xa1\xee\'$"\xc1\x85\xe0\x04\xd2wg5\x98\xbf\xb4\xd0\xacr\xd3\\\xbc\x9e\x00\xf1\x9d\xbe\xdb\xaa\xe6\x863Om\xcf\x0fc\xdeX\xfa\xa5\x18&\xd7\xcbh\x9db\xc9\xbeZ\xf6\xb7\xd3$\xcd\xa5\xeb\xc8\xa9\x9a\xfa\x85Z\xc5\xb3%~\xbc\xdf'

In [25]: decrypt("password",line.split(None,1)[1])
Out[25]: '12345678'

In [26]: "12345678" == decrypt("password",line.split(None,1)[1])
Out[26]: True
```

When you iterate over the file simple use `if line.startswith("Password")`...

```
with open(your_file) as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.startswith("Password"):
            password = line.rstrip().split(None,1)[1]
            # do your check
```

You could use a `dict` and `pickle` using `password`as a key then just do a lookup:

Comment: You've got a stray backtick at the beginning of your if... line.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell python to specifically read the password only?

data.txt:

```
[<< LOGIN >>]

Username: admin

Password: 12345678

E-Mail: hue@hue.hue

[<< LOGIN END >>]

[<< LOGIN >>]

Username: admin

Password: XxyYo345320945!@#!$@#!@#$%^%^^@#$%!@#$@!#41211 

E-Mail: hue@hue.hue

[<< LOGIN END >>]
```

...

```
import re

f = open('data.txt')

pattern = r"""
    Password     #Match the word 'Password', followed by...
    \s*          #whitespace(\s), 0 or more times(*), followed by...
    :            #a colon
    \s*          #whitespace, 0 or more times...
    (.*)         #any character(.), 0 or more times(*).  The parentheses 'capture' this part of the match.
"""

regex = re.compile(pattern, re.X)  #When you use a pattern over and over for matching, it's more efficient to 'compile' the pattern.

for line in f:
    match_obj = regex.match(line)

    if match_obj:  #then the pattern matched the line
        password = match_obj.group(1)  #group(1) is what matched the 'first' set of parentheses in the pattern
        print password

f.close()

--output:--
12345678
XxyYo345320945!@#!$@#!@#$%^%^^@#$%!@#$@!#41211
```

A regular expression (or RE) specifies a set of strings that matches it; the functions in this module let you check if a particular string matches a given regular expression (or if a given regular expression matches a particular string, which comes down to the same thing).

Regular expressions can be concatenated to form new regular expressions; if A and B are both regular expressions, then AB is also a regular expression. In general, if a string p matches A and another string q matches B, the string pq will match AB. This holds unless A or B contain low precedence operations; boundary conditions between A and B; or have numbered group references. Thus, complex expressions can easily be constructed from simpler primitive expressions like the ones described here. For details of the theory and implementation of regular expressions, consult the Friedl book referenced above, or almost any textbook about compiler construction.

A brief explanation of the format of regular expressions follows. For further information and a gentler presentation, consult the Regular Expression HOWTO.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re